# Angular 6 trouble understanding why my databinding is wrong

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

Good Morning,

I am a beginner with angular 6 and I am building a personnal website with Angular+NodeJs.

I am building an interface with 2 sections of 3 buttons, each button triggers a modal with a title (the button's name) and a body (an array of paragraphs with a content). Information such as section title, button name, modal body, is send by the node server as a JSON String.

Everything works fine on server side. the JSON string is well sent when my service on the front side makes the query. The button titles shows well on the screen, as well as the modal title, but not the modal body which refuses to show up.

I would like to understand why my modal title shows up correctly but not my modal contend, although it seems to me I am using the same kind of code to show both of them. I think I am missing a big issue about databinding.

my json :

```
[
    {id:1, title: "section title ...", buttons:[
      {
        id:1,
        text:"Button title 1",
        paraphs:[
          {id:1, content:"paraph1"},
          {id:2, content:"paraph2"}
        ]
      },
      {id:2, text:"Button title 2"},
      {id:3, text:"Button title 3"}
    ]},
    {id:2, title: "Section title 2", buttons:[
      {id:1, text:"Button title 1"},
      {id:2, text:"Button title 2"},
      {id:3, text:"Button title 3"}
    ]}
  ]
```

my component.html :

```
<div class="container spacer" >
  <div *ngFor="let section of sections">
    <div>
        <p class="fontPacifico_white">{{section.title}}</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row;justify-content: center; min-height: 250px;">
        <button class="section_button" type="button" *ngFor="let button of section.buttons" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" (click)="this.handleClick(button.text, button.paraphs)">{{button.text}}</button>
     </div>
  </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{modal_title}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" ngFor="let paraph of paraphs" *ngIf="!paraphs==undefined">
            <p>{{paraph.content}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

my component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PrestationService} from '../service/prestation.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prestation',
  templateUrl: './prestation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prestation.component.css']
})
export class PrestationComponent implements OnInit {


  sections;
  modal_title;
  paraphs;


  constructor(private ps:PrestationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ps.getPrestation().subscribe(
      data => this.sections = data
    )
  }

  handleClick(buttonTitle, buttonContent){
    this.modal_title = buttonTitle;
    this.paraphs = buttonContent;
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong here:

```
<div class="modal-body" ngFor="let paraph of paraphs" *ngIf="!paraphs==undefined">
  <p>{{paraph.content}}</p>
</div>
```

1. Your `ngFor` is missing a `*` (should be `*ngFor`)
2. You [cannot mix multiple strutural directives on the same element](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-structural-directive-per-host-element) (`*ngFor` and `*ngIf`)
3. Your condition is... quite weird, and probably never true (the negation of an array should be `false`, and `false == undefined` also yields `false`).

You should probably just drop the `*ngIf` altogether, since an empty array will never iterate anyway:

```
<div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let paraph of paraphs">
  <p>{{paraph.content}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right ... shame on me ! :) works perfect now, thank you

Comment: @PhilippeMerle You're welcome! (And nothing to be ashamed of.)